# Specman reflection: Generic method to copy list of any type

Tags: reflection, specman, e

I would like to write a generic method that copies list of any type.
My code:

```
copy_list(in_list : list of rf_type) : list of rf_type is {
    var out_list : list of rf_type;
    gen out_list keeping { it.size() == in_list.size(); };
    for each (elem) in in_list {
        out_list[index] = elem.unsafe();
    };
    result = out_list;
};
```

The method's call:

```
var list_a : list of uint;
gen list_a;
var list_b : list of uint;
list_b = copy_list(list_a);
```

The error:

```
   ERR_GEN_NO_GEN_TYPE: Type 'list of rf_type' is not generateable
(it is not a subtype of any_struct) at line ...
        gen out_list keeping { it.size() == in_list.size(); };
```

In addition, there is an error also when defining the method `copy_list` using `list of untyped`:

```
Error: 'list_a' is of type 'list of uint', while expecting
type 'list of untyped'.
```

Can you please help to write a generic method to copy list? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 4):

I think you're over-thinking your approach. You should just use the `copy()` pseudo-method:

```
extend sys {
  run() is also {
    var list1 : list of uint = { 1; 2; 3 };
    var list2 := list1;  // shallow copy, list2 points to list1
    var list3 : list of uint = list1.copy();

    list1.add(4);

    print list1, list2, list3;
  };
};
```

If you run the example, you'll see that `list2` will contain a 4 (because it's merely a reference to `list1`, whereas `list3` won't (because it's a new list that just contains the values `list1` contained when it was created).

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason not to use pseudo-method .copy()?

```
var list_a : list of uint;
gen list_a;
var list_b : list of uint;
list_b = list_a.copy();
```